# Cannot find module './favicon.ico.json' Express - NodeJs:

Tags: node.js, express, npm

My website (running on the express framework) suddenly started complaining that it needed a favicon.

```
app.get('/:translation/:book', (req, res) => {
    const {translation} = req.params
    console.log(translation)
    
    const file = require(`./${translation}.json`)
    res.json(file.books.filter((book, index) => index === req.params.book)[0])
});
```